# Creating an archive from a directory without the directory name being added to the archive

Tags: command-line, compression, 7-zip

I have the following folder structure:

> - root
>
>   - folder1
>   - folder2
>   - folder3
>   - 7za.exe

I want to run the 7-zip command line tool to compress all the files in `folder1` to a zip file called `folder1.zip`.

Running the following

```
7za.exe a -tzip folder1.zip folder1\\*.*
```

produces a zip file as expected. However, when I open the zip file, it has a folder in it called `folder1`, and inside that I have all the files that were inside that folder. I don't want the folder name added to the zip folder, i.e. I would like to add all the files in a "Flat" file format.

I also don't want to recursively run the command line tool for each individual file/folder.

Is there a switch that provides this functionality?

Comment: Can you `cd` into folder1 and `7za.exe a -tzip ..\folder1.zip *.*`?

Comment: He can, but then 7za.exe is not inside that folder, so running the original command won't work because it won't be able to find 7za.exe. Maybe using `start ..\7za.exe` might fix that but it's messy and 7-Zip should be able to do this, without having to do that.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

From the [7-Zip Help](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/index.htm) file:

> ### [a (Add) command](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/add.htm)
>
> Adds files to archive.
>
> Examples
>
> `7z a archive1.zip subdir\`
>
> adds all files and subfolders from folder subdir to archive archive1.zip. The filenames in archive will contain subdir\ prefix.
>
> `7z a archive2.zip .\subdir\*`
>
> adds all files and subfolders from folder subdir to archive archive2.zip. The filenames in archive will not contain subdir\ prefix.
>
> `cd /D c:\dir1\`
>
> `7z a c:\archive3.zip dir2\dir3\`
>
> The filenames in archive c:\archive3.zip will contain dir2\dir3\ prefix, but they will not contain c:\dir1\ prefix.

So the command you'd want would be: `7za.exe a folder1.zip .\folder1\*`

Also, pay attention to 7-Zip's handling of wildcards.  It doesn't treat `*.*` as "all files" -- it means "all files with a period in the filename."  Extension-less files will be missed.  If you really want all files, just use `*` instead.

Finally, the `-tzip` parameter isn't needed if the archive filename ends in `.zip`.  7-Zip is smart enough to figure out which format you want in those cases.  It's only required when you want a custom extension (e.g. `7za.exe a -tzip foo.xpi <files>` for a Mozilla Add-on).

Comment: This comment was really helpful. I'm trying to script 7zip to create zip archives for comic files, and had no idea that 7zip could save custom extensions. Now I don't have to rename the zip archives with a second program. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

Consider folder structure like C:\Parent\SubFolders..... And you want to create parent.zip which will contain all files and folders C:\Parent without parent folder [i.e it will start from SubFolders.....]

```
cd /D "C:\Parent"

"7z.exe" a Parent.zip "*.*" -r
```

This will create Parent.zip in C:\Parent

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: Well while I was searching for solution I didn’t get exact this solution. Obviously I will not just copy paste some answers I found online. I spend some time on it so I felt I should share it. As per me you can find this exact answer here and on Stack Overflow posted by me.

Comment: Note that 7-Zip does not consider `*.*` to mean "all files" but rather "all files that have a period as a part of the filename." So this answer will actually omit files that do not have an extension (this is noted in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the accepted answer (I was not able to add comment there):

On Linux adding '*' didn't work for me, so I ended up concocting more verbose command line which gave desired result:

```
curr_dir=$(pwd); \ 
cd source_code/lambda/ ; \
7z a ../../lambda.zip .; \
cd $curr_dir \
unset curr_dir
```

===========

script explanation:

- save current dir path to use later;
- navigate to directory which needs to be archived;
- create archive (notice '.' (dot) in the end);
- go back to the original dir;
- get rid of the variable which stored original dir path

I hope it might be useful for somebody.

Comment: I'd suggest to place the `*` in quotes (otherwise the shell will expand it to the files at this place).

Answer (score -5):

How about this. e.g. Folder/subFolder1, Folder/subfolder2

> select all subfolder > rightclick then create archive > select whatever format

*The archive name would be the parent folder..

Simple right?

Comment: The question is about the CLI for 7-zip, not how to use the GUI. Learning how to use the GUI is pointless when you want to automate things.