# 7-Zip command line to zip all the content of a folder (without zipping the folder itself)

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create an archive from a directory without the directory name being added to the archive](https://superuser.com/questions/340046/create-an-archive-from-a-directory-without-the-directory-name-being-added-to-the)

I have a folder that I want to zip completely:

```
MyFolder
       |
       |--- SubFolder1
       |--- SubFolder2
       |--- file1
       |--- file2
```

I want to zip everyting into myzip.7z, but I don't want 'MyFolder' to be inside the archive:

```
myzip.7z
       |
       |--- SubFolder1
       |--- SubFolder2
       |--- file1
       |--- file2
```

instead of

```
myzip.7z
       |
       |--- MyFolder
                   |
                   |--- SubFolder1
                   |--- SubFolder2
                   |--- file1
                   |--- file2
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 61):

This is how I did it.

```
cd MyFolder
7z a -r ../myzip *
```

This creates the archive (myzip.7z) in the parent of MyFolder rather than in MyFolder directly.

Alternatively (without first changing into MyFolder):

```
7z a myzip ./MyFolder/*
```

Comment: Thanx, done the same with winrar

Comment: About `-r`, `7z` manual says
"Recurse subdirectories (CAUTION: this flag does not do what you think, avoid using it)"

Comment: @GregoryPakosz looks like it recursively includes all sub directorys... based on this post, seems like thats the expectations, what do you think is the miss use and what should i do to get a folder and all of its subs?

Comment: `7z a myzip ./MyFolder/*` syntax works brilliantly. But it is an absurd syntax, I must say.